# Cannot read XML file in R to convert a dataframe?

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

Trying to read and convert a XML file to DataFrame from **FAERS** but cannot read the file in **R**
So far I have tried both `library(XML)` and `library(xml2)`

This error appears I have tried solutions online but does not work

```
> library(xml2)
> pg <- read_xml("faers/xml/ADR12Q4.xml")
Error in read_xml.character("faers/xml/ADR12Q4.xml") : 
  Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xB5 0x67 0x2F 0x64 [9]
```

Data is freely available in the link [Oct-Dec,2012](https://fis.fda.gov/extensions/FPD-QDE-FAERS/FPD-QDE-FAERS.html)

I have tried these
-- [Reading xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406949/reading-xml-in-r)
and [utf8_encode(.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507608/error-input-is-not-proper-utf-8-indicate-encoding-using-phps-simplexml-lo) does not work in R

Comment: Please include sample of XML in body of question (including its root and enough elements to understand structure) to avoid readers the burden of downloading form external links that may not be available or accessible by all now or in future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
> pg <- read_xml('path', encoding='UTF-8')
```

You have documentation **[here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xml2/versions/1.3.2/topics/read_xml)**.

**Edit**:
Try this code:

```
result <- XML::xmlParse("path_to_file")
```

This code worked for me. I was working of file that you specified in your question (*3_ADR20Q1.xml*)

Comment: still getting same error, "  Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xB5 0x67 0x2F 0x64 [9]"

Comment: So you have an answer. You have to check, what encoding you have in that file, and then pass is as an argument. You can check it in the first line of XML file.